# css 1, css 2, css 2.1 and css 3 , which css properties and selectors are different/new in each version?

Tags: css, w3c

CSS 1, CSS 2,  CSS 2.1 and CSS 3: which CSS properties and selectors are different in each version? I searched google a lot, but haven't found any list?

I need a list of the properties and selectors supported for each version with differences.

Comment: The quirksmode list is about as close to a list as you can get. What more do you want?

Comment: @cletus - quirksmode has list of selectors with cross browser support list not all css properties list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after more deep search finally i got my list here

http://www.htmlpedia.org/wiki/List_of_CSS_Properties

the only this is missed in this list is difference of css 2 and 2.1

### Edit:

Now i got my final answer here: http://meiert.com/en/indices/css-properties/

get list for html version also: http://meiert.com/en/indices/html-elements/

I also found some information here: http://www.rilem.de/css1pqre.htm

Comment: The meiert table is a great list, thanks for editing and posting.

Answer (score 4):

See [CSS master table](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html) or go straight to the W3C at [CSS1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS1/), [CSS 2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/) and [CSS 3](http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/current-work).

Basically there are lots of differences, too many to really summarize.

Comment: I think cletus is right. There will be too many to have in a list.

Comment: The question is about comparing CSS versions, the "CSS master table" is about browser comparisons.

Comment: How about CSS 4? any idea ?

Answer (score 2):

If you have to give a lecture you should immediately stop looking for a list, and do some of your own research. Explain things such as box model and how they have evolved over each iteration. That way you'll actually *know* what you're talking about, instead of being some guy reading a list to a class.

*Hint: nobody wants to hear you read a list off, your job is to digest this information and explain why the differences matter, which ones should be worried about, and which ones can be safely ignored*

Comment: but i have to show differences in each version with example and progress in each version. i know css well but from 2.1 only

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would get myself a good book on the subject.

I personally like [HTML, XHTML, and CSS, Sixth Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321430840). I bought it at a local Barnes and Noble and I've found it quite handy for questions like this. Also, look around for some good CSS books (sans HTML).

Eric Meyer would be your best bet in terms of authorship.

PS:

CSS 3 Adds lots of cool features like rounded corners and drop shadows.
Many of these new features are not yet supported by IE, FF, Opera, chrome and Safari. 
(Chrome, Opera and Safari need new abbreviations, really.)

Try looking at the CSS article on Wikipedia.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Css1#CSS_1

Comment: i have to give a lecture on css history and in that i have to explain css version differences

Comment: Then you should be fine with basic info. Try here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Css1#CSS_1